# Sending email with attachment using FileProvider

Tags: android, file, mobile

I try send mail with attachment by gmail with code below :

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto", "test@mail.com", null));

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "test Mail");
File file = ..function that return file with logs...


File newFile = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "logs" + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".log");

FileTools.fileCopy(file, newFile);

Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
            "test.test.test.provider", newFile);

emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "eMail"), 1);
```

also I added path to folder logs

```
<files-path  name="logs" path="logs/" />
```

It runs gmail app with toast "couldn't attach file".
In debug uri variable looks that:

> content://test.test.test.provider/logs/1545415598572.log

When I changed

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "test.test.test.provider", newFile);
```

with

```
Uri uri = Uri.uri(newFile);
```

it works but only with files in external storage.

Why it doesn't work with FileProvider?

Comment: Did you create provider in the Android Manifest file?

Comment: yes, I sees that FileProvider it's used in other place in project and it works so it's correct.

Comment: Just a moment, i will show my example how i did it. Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Application package - ru.exampleapp
**file_provider.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Then added provider in the Android manifest.

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="ru.exampleapp"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_provider" />
</provider>
```

Here is an example, how to create and start intent.

```
val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
val devInfoFile = context.getFileStreamPath("debug_info.txt")
val outputWriter = OutputStreamWriter(devInfoFile.outputStream())
outputWriter.write("Model: ${Build.MODEL}\n")
outputWriter.write("Id: ${Build.ID}\n")
outputWriter.write("Manufacturer: ${Build.MANUFACTURER}\n")
var devInfoUri: Uri? = null
try {
    devInfoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "ru.exampleapp", devInfoFile)
} catch (e: java.lang.Exception) { }
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, devInfoUri)
emailIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf(context.getString(R.string.admin_email)))
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.selector = emailIntent
try {
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, 
    context.getString(R.string.report_message)))
} catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
}
```

Also i added selector, it is way how to send only via email app.